# Specify the publisher name for Windows's User Account Control (UAC) when using NSIS?

Tags: windows, installation, uac, nsis

Is it possible to specify the publisher name for Windows's User Account Control (UAC) when using NSIS (Nullsoft Scriptable Install System)?

[image]

Comment: I think you have to digitally sign the installer.

Comment: @Luke, if you put that down as the answer, I would give you credit for answering the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must digitally sign the installer.

Answer (score 2):

You need to digitally sign the installer, unfortunately this is somewhat ugly in NSIS code since executing signtool at the correct moment is [tricky](http://nsis.pastebin.com/rJAEFF53).

Comment: I have actually a far simpler mechanism of signing the installer. Basically I write the uninstaller from a script uninstall.nsi, install it to $EXEDIR, sign that file, package the installer, and sign the resulting file. All this is automated from an outside program so my two NSI scripts are clean.